# What happens when PCIe boost circuits are overloaded?

Tags: crash, performance, mac-pro, power-management, gpu

In my understanding, the 2010 Mac Pro is rated for 75W of power for each PCIe slot, plus 75W for each of the two 6-pin boost (aux) circuits.  I know it's possible to exceed these limits, because I do it regularly. At what point does it have some effect, and what is that effect?  I'd like a very specific answer, not just, "it crashes".  My guesses:

- A thermal or power sensor trips and kills power to the offending circuit.
- A sensor trips and kills power to the whole PSU
- The motherboard traces melt and cause a fire
- The OS kills the process that is over-using the GPU

Obviously, any of these options would cause the computer to crash.  My computer sometimes reboots spontaneously when I'm doing heavy GPU processing, and I just want to understand exactly what is happening.

Interesting sidenote:  after this type of crash, I always have to reinstall the Blackmagic Desktop Video driver before my DeckLink will be recognized.

Answer (score 1):

Still running strong 30% overclock..

https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/mac-pro-4-1-and-5-1-pcie-aux-power.2035519/